# Evaluating $\int_0^1xf(x)dx$ when $\int^1_0F(x)dx=10, F'(x)=f(x)$ and $F(1)=e$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am given the following information:

$$\int^1_0F(x)dx=10$$
$$F'(x)=f(x)$$
$$F(1)=e$$

I am first asked to evaluate $\frac{d}{dx}[xF(x)]$ which I found to be:

$$\frac{d}{dx}[xF(x)]=F(x)+xf(x)$$

Then it says to rearrange this answer to find the integral:

$$\int^1_0xf(x)dx$$

But I'm not exactly sure where to go from there. I know I can sub in $\int^1_0F(x)dx=10$ for $F(x)$ at some point, but don't know how to set it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you have found that $$\frac{d}{dx}xF(x) = F(x) + xf(x)$$, try integrating.

See what you get from $$\int_{0}^{1}d(xF(x)) = \int_{0}^{1}\left(F(x)+xf(x)\right)dx$$

Comment: It should be $\int_0^1\,d(xF(x))=\int_0^1(F(x)+xf(x))\,dx$ in the final line.

Comment: @StubbornAtom fixed, thanks. why delete your answer?

Comment: Because it's not needed.

Comment: I get that part, but what I'm not sure of is how to evaluate the definite integral of $d(xF(x))$

Comment: @PatrickRobertson Integration is the inverse operation of differentiation, thus if $$F'(x) = f(x)$$ we have $$F'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F(x) = f(x) \implies \int_{a}^{b}d(F(x)) = F(b)-F(a)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$ so in this case $$\int_{0}^{1}d(xF(x)) = 1\cdot F(1) - 0\cdot F(0)$$

Comment: @PatrickRobertson Not a problem.